# Google earth will not reinstall

Tags: package-management, google-earth

I was trying to perform the the fix found at this link
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/how-to-make-google-earth-look-native-in-ubuntu

It requires you to delete certain files from the /opt/google/earth/free folder and then add some new ones that you download. I deleted the files but the links to download the new ones were unusable. I was using `gksudo nautilus` so trash was disabled meaning I could not restore the files I had deleted. I the tried to go to the Google Earth website and reinstall it. I downloaded the .deb but when I tried to install it it gav me an error message saying "cannot install ia32-libs" I tried installing this via terminal and it gave me an error message saying

> chad@chad-Lenovo-G570:~$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
>
> [sudo] password for chad:
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Now I am stuck without a functioning Google Earth. How can I fix this?

Comment: It may not be anything you have done, you may be affected by this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synaptic/+bug/971761 It might pay you to read through the comments as many of them have managed to solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i finally figured it out. I ran the commands

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module`

`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to skip bashing you for allowing some random clueless guy on a random website to tell you what files to delete from your machine. I think you already get the idea.

If you did not download *ANY* files from their website, chances are you haven't compromised your OS installation yet. Otherwise all bets are off and you should reinstall your machine, no exceptions if you want to be safe, that is.

**Reinstall packages you broke by deleting their parts earlier**

First of all - you need to reinstall the packages files from which you have deleted. You can do this by verifying your packages with debsums:

```
sudo debsums -c
```

It's going to take some time. This is its output after I've manually removed /usr/bin/zipnote that belonged to the zip package.

```
$ sudo debsums -c
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/icon-theme.cache
debsums: no md5sums for libaudio2
/var/lib/nvidia-common/last_gfx_boot
debsums: missing file /usr/bin/zipnote (from zip package)
```

You can see the /usr/bin/zipnote as a missing file. You can also see `/var/lib/nvidia-common/last_gfx_boot` file which has a different checksum. You could choose to reinstall the relevant packages just to be safe. You can find out which package owns that file by running:

```
$ dpkg -S /var/lib/nvidia-common/last_gfx_boot
nvidia-common: /var/lib/nvidia-common/last_gfx_boot
```

Then after you get the list of packages that you need to reinstall run:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall package1 package2 packageN
```

**Fix ia32-libs**

First verify the state of this package. It can be removed but there can be some parts of it left. Run:

```
dpkg -l ia32-libs
```

if it's anything other than

```
un  ia32-libs       <none>               (no description available)
```

run:

```
sudo dpkg --purge ia32-libs
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade #(optional but strongly recommended)
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

And finally download and install Google Earth:

```
wget http://dl.google.com/dl/earth/client/current/google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Comment: None of the packages shown after running 'sudo debsums -c' have to do with ia32-libs

Comment: That point wasn't strictly about ia32-libs, there's a separate part on it later in my post. Have you found and reinstalled the other broken packages as found by debsums?

Comment: yes I followed all of your steps and when I reinstall google earth it gives me the same error

Comment: Take a look at Chris Carter's comment underneath your question and see if this affects you. Also printing the output of `apt-cache policy ia32-libs-multiarch` and the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` would be helpful.

Comment: ia32-libs-multiarch:i386:

  Installed: (none)

  Candidate: 20090808ubuntu36

  Version table:
     20090808ubuntu36 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/universe i386 Packages

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling ia32-libs `sudo apt-get purge ia32-libs` then `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` then try installing google earth again. If anymore packages have issues do that same for them. For future reference it usually isn't wise to do things like that with out saving the original files. Also you should probably use more discretion over things like this; the files they want you to download could easily have malware even if you trust the author/publisher I doubt they have reviewed the code.

Comment: Yes thank you I realize it was a stupid thing to do. ia32-libs is not installed in the first place so uninstalling it and reinstalling it is not an option

Comment: Did you check to make sure; just because you didn't do it yourself doesn't mean it wasn't a dependency for some other program

Comment: Yes when I run the purge command it tells me that ia32-libs is not installed and therefore cannot be removed

Comment: did you originally install via a repository or a deb file

Comment: a deb file i think but it was a long time ago

Comment: try finding the version number for that install then the deb file of the same version otherwise I don't know what to tell you